# Looking to select only first of set

Tags: mysql

In my query I am able to successfully extract the mass data, however it would be very helpful if I am able to drill down to only selecting the first project start date of the data set.

I've tried adding a (MIN) to my query but it errors out, any suggestions ?

For clarification, I am looking to select the first project start date on a particular contract. Any contract can have (n) # of projects. My goal is to detect the first of them.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONT.CONTRACTNUMBER as "Contract Number",

            CS.PRODUCTID as "Product ID",

            PROJ.PROJECTID as "Project ID",

            PR.PRODDESCRIPTION as "Product Description",

            PROJ.PROJECTNAME as "Project Name",

            CS.STARTDT as "Contract Service/ Product Start DT",

            CONT.CONTRACTStartDT as "Contract Start DT",

            PROJ.PROJECTSTARTDT as "Project Start DT",

Datediff(DAY, CS.STARTDT, PROJ.PROJECTSTARTDT) as "# Day Difference"

FROM   PRODUCTDATA.DBO.HHCONTRACTSERVICE CS WITH(NOLOCK)

LEFT OUTER JOIN COSTTRACKERDATA.DBO.OAPROJECT PROJ WITH(NOLOCK)

ON CS.DID = PROJ.EXTERNALID

LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCTDATA.DBO.HHCONTRACT CONT WITH(NOLOCK)

ON CS.CONTRACTDID = CONT.DID

LEFT OUTER JOIN FIGURES..DIMPRODUCT PR WITH(NOLOCK)

ON CS.PRODUCTID = PR.PRODUCTID

AND PR.SUBPRODUCTLINE IN ( 'S', 'S' )

WHERE  CS.STARTDT BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-11-11'

AND PROJ.PROJECTSTARTDT <> '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'

order by [Contract Number], [Project Start DT]
```

Comment: You should post the exact error you get and perhaps include some sample data or at the very least the datatypes for the fields your query is using. If you use MIN(...) you need to include an aggregator clause like 'group by'.

Answer (score 0):

First in the list or the earliest date in the list?

either way you can order your list the way you want and add `limit 1` at the end. That will give you the first row only.

> The LIMIT clause is used in the SELECT statement to constrain the number of rows to return.

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Comment: Hello! Thank you for responding. So I'm not sure if the server spits out the project start dates in chronological order but I will try this. But to clarify more, I am looking for the first project start date on a given contract, there can be multiple projects per contract.

Comment: I went and ahead and tried the LIMIT clause unfortunately it didn't work. I also altered the query to order by the project ST date ASC